# How to call random Function in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, function, random

So I have this functions, I was wondering how can I call the two function randomly. I mean, the php code will randomly select from the two? how can I do that?

**Example Functions**

```
    function one() {
        echo '
<div id="two-post">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('dos'); ?>

        <div class="entry-meta">
            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <p>By <?php the_author(); ?></p>
        </div>

        <div class="overlay2"></div>
    </a>
</div>

';
    }

    function two() {
        echo '<div class="two">' . wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 50, '' ) . '</div>';
    }

    function three() { // function names without "-"
        echo '<div class="third">' . the_author() .'</div>';
    }
```

**The code for selecting the two functions randomly**

```
<?php

$functions = array('one', 'two', 'three'); // remove the open and close parenthesis () in the strings

call_user_func($functions[array_rand($functions)]);

?>
```

The code above doesn't work. Was wonder if someone could help?

Comment: You cannot have a function name with "-"

Comment: got this error:

Function name must be a string in D:\Xampp\htdocs\...php on line 12

Comment: `add_shortcode` takes two strings, so add `''` around the callable name.

Comment: You are still calling the functions the wrong way. You got them as upper case strings, still including the parentheses. Read my answer.

Comment: Or you might not be using the code in the bottom of your question? Then please post the error. (also, you are echo'ing out the result of the function, but the function itself echos inside, remove the echo from the function call or let the function return the data instead of echo'ing it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call it something like this:

```
function one() {
    echo '
        <div id="two-post">
            <a href="' . the_permalink() .'" alt="' . the_title() .'" title="' . the_title() .'">
                ' . the_post_thumbnail('dos') . '

                <div class="entry-meta">
                    <h1>' . the_title() . '</h1>
                    <p>By ' . the_author() . '</p>
                </div>

                <div class="overlay2"></div>
            </a>
        </div>
    ';
}

function two() {
    echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 50, '' );
}

function three() { // function names without "-"
    echo '<div>' . the_author() .'</div>';
}

$functions = array('one', 'two', 'three'); // remove the open and close parenthesis () in the strings

$functions[array_rand($functions)](); // call it!

// or
call_user_func($functions[array_rand($functions)]);
```

Comment: Thank you ghost! i tried your code unfortunately, i have an error located at this line:

    echo '<?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 50, $more = '...' ); ?>';

Comment: you may see my revised function above.

Comment: no @KareenLagasca remove the PHP's in that just echo it, check my revision

Comment: I removed the <?php so this is now the code:

 echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 50, $more = '...' ); ?>';

but then, the errors is now in this lines echo '<div><?php the_title(); ?></div>'; and echo '<div><?php the_author(); ?></div>';

Comment: @KareenLagasca i revised my answer, take a look

Comment: there's a little problem with the code... the lines with <div>' . the_title() . '</div> returns something like this:

<div></div>TITLE

the problem is the <?php the_title?> is outside the <div></div>, it should be inside right?

Comment: @KareenLagasca right outside the div? that's odd, what does `the_title()` return anyway? is that another div? or just a simple string?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61157/discussion-between-kareen-lagasca-and-ghost).

Comment: @KareenLagasca check my revision, it seems this is the correct way to use it: CODEX http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title

Comment: Ghost, what if i want to put a chunk of codes in function one just like one above (I revised my code above). how can I do that?

Comment: @KareenLagasca wow you're asking piece by piece, and this is just string concatenation. when you are echoing, just concatenate the function on the strings, anyway this question is getting broad, check the revision

Answer (score 3):

You can use Switch case here...

```
function one(){
             //some code;
             }
function two(){
             //some code;
             }
function random_caller(){
          int x = rand(0,1);
          switch(x){
          case 1: one();
          break;
          case 2: two();
          break;
          default: echo "could not run any function";
          break;
            }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the parentheses in the array with function names, like: `$a=array("FUNCTION-ONE","FUNCTION-TWO");` And add them on call: `echo $a[$random_keys[0]]() . "<br>";`

Also, PHP will be a bit annoyed with function names containing the `-` character (cant name functions like that), so try rename the functions to something like: `functionOne` (which would also more fit the php standard).

```
<?php
$functions = array("functionOne","functionTwo");
$function = array_rand($functions); // no second param uses default param which is 1, and will only return one entry.
echo $functions[$function]() ."<br>";
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function one()   { echo 'ONE'; }
function two()   { echo 'TWO'; }
function three() { echo 'THREE'; }

$functions = array('one', 'two', 'three');
call_user_func($functions[array_rand($functions)]);
```

---

Or in a function:

```
function callRandomFunction($functions)
{
    call_user_func($functions[array_rand($functions)]);
}
```

Called like:

```
callRandomFunction($functions);
```