# Is it possible with RevSlider?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, slider

I have a client (logistic-people . de) that has the same RevSlider on each page. It has 6 slides but they wanted to show only one slide at a time, randomly. So I set RevSlider like this:

In "Loop And Progress" tab:
* Stop Slider: On
* Stop After Loops: 0
* Stop At Slide: 1

In "General Settings" tab:
* Shuffle Mode: On

Now my problem is that, even if the slider is showing as intended, it is not quite optimized yet. It loads ALL 6 slides in the code of the page, even though it only shows 1 slide at a time.

Case 1: Let's say we have our slider with 6 different slide animations. Is it possible to show only one random slide from the 6 existing slides without loading all 5 slides in page's code?

Case 2: Let's say I have 10 sliders but I want to select only the 6 of them I created for our problem, to be displayed randomly one at a time, on a page. Is there any way I can select specific sliders, not all of  them based on this code https://www.themepunch.com/faq/show-a-random-slider-on-any-given-page/​

Case 3: Is there any other WP slider plugin that can solve our problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue :) Based on [How to call random Function in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25820056/how-to-call-random-function-in-php) I created 6 sliders with just one slide then I randomized them:

```
function functia_unu() { echo do_shortcode('[rev_slider homepage1]'); }
function functia_doi() { echo do_shortcode('[rev_slider homepage2]'); }
function functia_trei() { echo do_shortcode('[rev_slider homepage3]'); }
function functia_patru() { echo do_shortcode('[rev_slider homepage4]'); }
function functia_cinci() { echo do_shortcode('[rev_slider homepage5]'); }
function functia_sase() { echo do_shortcode('[rev_slider homepage6]'); }

$executafunctiile = array('functia_unu', 'functia_doi', 'functia_trei', 'functia_patru', 'functia_cinci', 'functia_sase');

$executafunctiile[array_rand($executafunctiile)]();
```